# Is CFUUIDCreate evenly distributed across all it's bits?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

I'm interested if anyone knows if the returned ID from CFUUIDCreate... is evenly distributed across all its bits. More specific: if you truncate some bits from it, will it still be evenly distributed ?

I'm asking this to know for example if it can be used as a hashing function, and how many collisions will it have if i strip down some bits of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It highly depends on the version of the generated UUID, from the docs it looks like Apple is using [version 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Version_1_.28MAC_address.29) (you can check the actual implementation at [opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com), it should be in the Core Foundation framework). Version 1 (and 2) doesn't have uniformly distributed bits, so you will lose uniqueness when you start cutting of its bits. What you can do is to hash the UUID using SHA256 or something like that which will have uniformly distributed bits.

Edit: I just checked [CFUUID.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFUUID.c) from the latest Core Foundation release (744.18 at the time of writing), and `CFUUIDRef CFUUIDCreate(CFAllocatorRef alloc)` appears to be using [`uuid_generate_random`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/uuid_generate_random.3.html) in all cases (there is branch that checks a boolean named `useV1UUIDs` which is always false). According to the man page, `uuid_generate_random` will use `/dev/urandom/` to create the UUID, which would give the resulting UUID uniformly distributed bits. Not sure if I would count on it being always random though, the implementation might change in the future.

Comment: awesome answer. thanks! now i know where to look for future reference. To sum up: the conclusion is : as of now it is uniformly distributed, but no guarantee that in future versions it will remain the same. Because it's not part of the specification/design that it should be. Also sha-ing or md5-ing it is definitely an easy "fix" to it's distribution.